# How does Flask flash message work and why does it require a cookie?

Tags: python, flask

A web framework, Flask, in Python has a functionality to flash messages. It requires to access signed cookie, but I'm not sure why it needs to access cookie. The document states as quoted below. When does it store and how? Does it need a cookie to identify which user is accessing?

> The flashing system basically makes it possible to record a message at the end of a request and access it on the next (and only the next) request.

- Flask document for message flashing
  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#message-flashing

Comment: _Does it need a cookie to identify which user is accessing_ This is one common use of cookies, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flask, the `flash()` function is used to generate messages that can be stored across requests. This allows for messages to be displayed to the user after a redirect, for example, indicating whether an action was successful or not.

The messages are stored in a cookie that is sent to the client's browser along with the response. The cookie is signed to prevent tampering and is only valid for the next request. When the next request is made, Flask checks for the existence of the cookie and retrieves the message if it exists.

The cookie is used to identify the user who is accessing the messages. Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, Flask uses cookies to maintain a state between requests. When the user makes a request, the cookie is sent back to the server, allowing Flask to identify the user and retrieve any stored messages.

So, Flask stores the messages in a signed cookie to identify which user is accessing and to maintain the state between requests.

CMIIW

Comment: Thank you so much. It's much clear now makes sense now that `flash` is useful when returning redirect response.